# magento update configurable product price programatically

Tags: magento

I need to update configurable product price. Can anyone tell me how to do that please. I spent more time on this , but still I am unable to find a proper way.

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure the configurable product price is used. It's the component simple products that are priced. (I use the Simple Configurable Products extension so that might affect how pricing is seen.)

Comment: Mention which all ways you have tried.